# How is it possible to end while (true) loop without break statement?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga

I was going through redux-saga channel documentation. Where I ran into the code:

```
export function* saga() {
  const chan = yield call(countdown, value)
  try {    
    while (true) {
      let seconds = yield take(chan)
      console.log(`countdown: ${seconds}`)
    }
  } finally {
    if (yield cancelled()) {
      chan.close()
      console.log('countdown cancelled')
    }    
  }
}
```

As you can see it is an infinite loop which will never end, you should either call break or throw and exception. But in the example above none is the case. There is no break or exception being thrown in the code above or within the calling functions. How is it possible that the above infinite loop ends and reaches the finally block?

see: http://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/advanced/Channels.html

Comment: Why do you say no exception is thrown? (My guess would be that an exception is thrown.)

Comment: Didn't you wonder what `yield` does, or the `*` after `function`? *"There is no ... exception being thrown in ... the calling functions"* - What about in the *called* functions? What does `take()` do?

Comment: I know how generators work. I have gone through the source code and I don't find any exception being handled gracefully.

Comment: @mahadazad Have you tried adding a `catch` block to see what exception is being thrown? That might make it easier to find in the source code.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at what's in the `countdown` function you'll see a special `END` action is emitted if `secs` is not greater than 0.

```js
import { eventChannel, END } from 'redux-saga'

function countdown(secs) {
  return eventChannel(emitter => {
      const iv = setInterval(() => {
        secs -= 1
        if (secs > 0) {
          emitter(secs)
        } else {
          // this causes the channel to close
          emitter(END)
          clearInterval(iv)
        }
      }, 1000);
      // The subscriber must return an unsubscribe function
      return () => {
        clearInterval(iv)
      }
    }
  )
}
```

(snippet above is from: http://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/advanced/Channels.html)

The `END` action is mentioned in the documentation for `take(pattern)` here:
http://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/api/index.html#takepattern

Answer (score 1):

This line seems throws exception, at some call

```
yield take(chan)
```

yield by it self return value, so there no infinite loop at all.

UPDATE: more details on how yield works can be found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield

Comment: I know how generators work. I thought that runSaga is  handling the exception gracefully, in this way we won't need to handle the exception in the above code and finally will also be called. But I don't see such code in the source.

Answer (score 1):

The above example will break out of the loop because of redux-saga's race which can be found in the example referenced [here](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga/blob/master/examples/cancellable-counter/src/sagas/index.js#L54-L57).

There is a component in the example, which when clicked dispatches the CANCEL_INCREMENT_ASYC action. The saga catches that action and fires of the [race effect](https://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/advanced/RacingEffects.html).

Because the incrementAsync function runs on a while loop (its essentially the same function you posted above), the take(CANCEL_INCREMENT_ASYNC) resolves first. The losing function in the race (the above posted one), gets an error thrown as a result which will resume the saga into the `finally` block.

Here's a [link to the race-effect saga](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga/blob/master/examples/cancellable-counter/src/sagas/index.js#L48-L62) that can lead to cancellation.